# Is it possible to parse dictionary of list to TFRecord file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

I want to create a TFRecord file which looks something like this:

```py
dataset = {
    "regions": [{
        "width": _int64_feature(),
        "height": _int64_feature(),
        "x": _int64_feature(),
        "y": _int64_feature()
    },
    {
        "width": _int64_feature(),
        "height": _int64_feature(),
        "x": _int64_feature(),
        "y": _int64_feature()
    },

    ...

    {
        "width" : _int64_feature(),
        "height": _int64_feature(),
        "x" : _int64_feature(),
        "y" : _int64_feature()
    }],
    "image_raw": _bytes_feature()
}
```

where dataset dictionary has regions and image_raw, and regions is a list of dictionary of bounding boxes data - width, height, x, y.

---

I tired doing this:

```
features = {}
regions = []
dset = {}
for i in range(len(file[0])):
  features["width"] = _int64_feature(file[0][i]["width"])
  features["height"] = _int64_feature(file[0][i]["height"])
  features["x"] = _int64_feature(file[0][i]["x"])
  features["y"] = _int64_feature(file[0][i]["y"])
  regions.append(features)
dset["image_data"] = _bytes_feature(img_string)
dset["regions"] = regions
```

Here, `file[0][i]` represents the `i`th bounding box data of `0`th image. Parsing this into

```
example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=dset))
```

throws a error saying

```
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected tensorflow.Feature got list.
```

Is there a way to correct this error or to do this in some other way?